# Vectorized matrix calculation comparing a relational matrix and taking the minimum in Python

Tags: python, numpy

**Matrices**

I want to create a vectorized approach (numpy) to populate/calculate the matrix called "qtyP" using input from the matrices "qtyC" and "rel". It is easy to solve in for loops but I would like to do it in a smarter way. First I will describe my matrices.

**Product vs week matrix (end result)**

```
# This is the desired end-result matrix (5x6)
# It describes how much of each product is available per week
# Rows: Products (5)
# Columns: Weeks (6)

qtyP = [[0,3,0,10,22,53],
        [0,0,75,154,213,250],
        [0,0,75,154,213,250],
        [0,0,75,154,213,250],
        [0,0,17,68,133,180]]
qtyP = np.matrix(qtyP)
```

**Capacity vs week matrix**

```
# This matrix (5x6) describes how much of each capacity is available per week
# Rows: Capacities (5)
# Columns: Weeks (6)

qtyC = [[0,0,17,68,133,180],
        [0,0,75,154,213,250],
        [0,0,39,11,34,100],
        [0,0,357,648,861,1531],
        [0,3,0,10,22,53]]
qtyC = np.matrix(qtyC)
```

**Product vs capacity relationship matrix**

```
# This matrix (5x5) details the relationship between "Products" and "Capacities".
# If there is a 1 then that capacity is needed for the product
# e.g. capacity 5 is need for product 1
# e.g. capacity 2 and 4 is needed for product 2
# Rows: Products (5)
# Columns: Capacities (5)

rel = [[0,0,0,0,1],
       [0,1,0,1,0],
       [0,1,0,1,0],
       [0,1,0,1,0],
       [1,0,0,1,0]]
rel = np.matrix(rel)
```

**How to get the end-result**

I will explain how I did this with for loops so that it is better explained.

1. For each row/product in *qtyP* check what capacities are needed by looking at *rel*
2. For the capacities needed, find the minimum quantity of those in *qtyC*
3. Populate for the current row in *qtyP* the minimum quantity of needed capacities for all six weeks

The rows in *qtyP* are the rows in *rel* and the rows in *qtyC* are the columns in *rel*. The reason to take the minimum quantity of the capacities included in a product is because that is what is possible to build. In this example I happen to have 5 products and 5 capacities, but it could be 3 products and 5 capacities as well. Then the *rel* matrix would be a (3x5), the *qtyC* matrix would be a (5x6) and the *qtyP* matrix would be a (3x6).

Is there a way to this in a vectorized approach? I tried something as the code below but I can't seem to get it right on both the order of the products and how to include the minimum function.

```
qtyP = qtyC[rel[np.newaxis,:] != 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT -** Changing my answer based on the comments.

IIUC, here is what you can do -

1. Since, before you can calculate the minimum, you need the different quantities for each product for each week, what you need to construct is a `(6,5,5)` tensor with `broadcasting`. For each `week (6)`, for each `product (5)` get the product of the corresponding value with the `rel row (5)`.
2. In this matrix you will now be able to take a `minimum` over the last `axis=-1` to get a `(6,5)` matrix.
3. However, because there are zeros, np.min wont work directly. So what you can do is use a `masked_array` to mask the `0` values and then find a `minimum` over `axis=-1`
4. Finally `fill` the masked values if returned, by 0 and `transpose` to get a (5,6) matrix.

```
b = qtyC.T[:,None,:] * rel   #(6,5,5)
c = np.ma.masked_array(b, mask=b==0).min(-1)
qtyP = c.filled(0).T
print(qtyP)
```

```
array([[  0,   3,   0,  10,  22,  53],
       [  0,   0,  75, 154, 213, 250],
       [  0,   0,  75, 154, 213, 250],
       [  0,   0,  75, 154, 213, 250],
       [  0,   0,  17,  68, 133, 180]])
```

Do check and let me know if this handles your edge cases.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and suggested approach. It seems that your suggestion works with the numbers given here, however when I reduce the quantity of capacities in `qtyC` in for example taking down the 1531 to 10 then this suggested approach results in the wrong matrix answer.

Comment: I think then I am incorrectly reading what rel is doing. can you explain what rel is? each row separately?

Comment: I describe the rel in detail within the code block with header "Product vs Capacity relationship matrix". Each row is a product and describes what capacities in the columns it needs to have. So product 1 only has capacity no. 5 while product 2 has capacity no. 2 and 4. This means that for each week one needs to check the minimal capacity per product to know how much can be built. So for product 2 in week 4 we have capacity 2 at 154 and capacity 4 at 648 and the minimum of these two is 154 which can be built of product 2. Amount of products built are: `qtyP(2,4) = min[qtyC(2,4) , qtyC(4,4)]`

Comment: ohhh its capacity number? its the index? got it.

Comment: Updated my solution. Do check and let me know.

Comment: It seems to work well! Will test out a few numbers more, but so far so good with different cases. Thanks a lot for your time and response!